# Azure: how to count storage transactions

Tags: azure, transactions, backup, storage

Can anyone explain me how count storage transactions ?
For example, I need storage for 10 GB, and daily incremental is about 100mb.
How to count the transactions ?

[image: Azure]

Answer (score 2):

Azure Storage Team had published a blog long time back on this - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx. To understand how you're going to get charged for using Azure Storage, I would highly recommend reading this post.

Azure Storage also provides detailed analytics on the operations performed against your storage account. You can find information about the transactions by looking at storage analytics data. You may find this link helpful for that: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/tags/analytics+*2d00*+logging+_2600_amp_3b00_+metrics/](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/tags/analytics+_2d00_+logging+_2600_amp_3b00_+metrics/).

Comment: This blog entry is not very helpful

Comment: @Dan May I know why did you make the comment? Which blog entry did you not find useful. It may not be a bad idea to ask a new question with your doubts.

Comment: Both links are dead

Comment: It's possible to view it with the Wayback Machine. Here's a link to a version of the page (first link) from 2011: http://web.archive.org/web/20111024210002/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Every single access to the storage counts as one transaction (even local, EDIT: eg. web-app to storage). Then you just have to calculate an average.

[Read more](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/)

> Transactions include both read and write operations to storage.